# Default Date assignment fails to occur

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script

I don't know what I'm missing here. As long as the user puts some date in the dialog box, everything is ok, but if the user leave the dialog empty, I've expected to have `d1` and `d2` set with the predefined dates, but it doesn't work:

```
var d1, d2, d1i, d2i;
// set default initial dates
d1i = "01/01/2010";
d2i = "01/01/2020";
d1 = new Date(Browser.inputBox("Insert first day in format M/D/Y. Leave empty for default " + d1i));
d2 = new Date(Browser.inputBox("Insert last day in format M/D/Y. Leave empty for default " + d2i));
// If the dialog boxes are left empty, set d1 and d2 with default values
if (d1 == "") {d1 = new Date(d1i);}
if (d2 == "") {d2 = new Date(d2i);}

var events = cal.getEvents(d1, d2, {search: text});
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
  var row = i + 2;
  var details = [[
    events[i].getTitle(),
    events[i].getDescription(),
    events[i].getLocation(),
    events[i].getStartTime(),
    events[i].getEndTime(),
    myformula_placeholder
  ]];
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 6);
  range.setValues(details);
}
```

I've also tried:

```
if (d1 == "") {d1 = d1i;}
if (d2 == "") {d2 = d2i;}
```

without success. The default dates are not used.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Edit your question with actual details of your specific issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Consider that an empty input results in `new Date("")` which is fundamentally not equivalent to `""`

Comment: OK, if inputboxes are left empty, I've expected d1 and d2 to be set as empty strings. Instead, d1 and d2 are set with the value string 'Invalid Date'. Now I've changed the code with: if (d1 == "Invalid Date") { d1 = d1i;}. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK, if inputboxes are left empty, I've expected d1 and d2 to be set as empty strings. Instead, d1 and d2 are set with the value string 'Invalid Date'. Now I've changed the code with:

```
if (d1 == "Invalid Date") { d1 = d1i;}.
if (d2 == "Invalid Date") { d2 = d2i;}
```

Any better solution is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have - an invalid Date parsing on blank input - and the lack of default `Date` usage in its place, are due to the position of the `Date` constructor call.

Instead of immediately instantiating the Date objects, validate and sanitize your user inputs first. This is most sensibly done in a separate function.

```
function getEnteredDate_(ui, promptMsg, defaultInput) {
  const resp = ui.prompt(promptMsg);
  const input = resp.getResponseText().trim();
  if (!input)
    input = defaultInput;

  // Sanitize text for date parsing
  ...

  // Now create the date.
  var myDate = new Date(input);
  // and verify proper construction
  ...

  // Use it
  return myDate;
}
```

Usage would be then:

```
// set default initial dates
const d1i = "01/01/2010";
const d2i = "01/01/2020";

const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var d1 = getEnteredDate_(ui, "Insert first day in format M/D/Y. Leave empty for default " + d1i, d1i);
var d2 = getEnteredDate_(ui, "Insert last day in format M/D/Y. Leave empty for default " + d2i, d2i);
...
```